# Why is "Close the door." translated to "Tür zu."?

Tags: translation, word-usage

How does the meaning of "Close the door." come from "Tür zu."?

I get that *Tür* means *door*. But how does *zu* mean *close*? I thought *zu* means *to* or *too*, and I can't fathom what I'm not understanding.

Comment: First: "Tür zu" would in most circumstances be considered rude. Second the link is "zumachen" (here: schließen, to close) With the prefix "zu" coming from the adverb "zu" meaning "in direction of". I could only speculate about the exact origin of the change from "make it in that direction" (i.e. move) to close. So I leave that to a real answer

Comment: If I said "Tür zu" in a soft, friendly voice would that still be considered rude? Like say in an informal situation, say at a movies with friends you have your hands full could you say to your friend "Tür zu" or would that still be considered rude, even if you know the person and don't use an aggressive voice? This exchange came this movie I was watching last night, the character said "Tür zu" and the subtitles said "close the door" but I couldn't understand why. The character was angry though, the person he said Tür zu to left open the door and the wind was strongly blowing through the room..

Comment: *Tür zu* in any case is very impolite. You could soften it by saying *Tür zu, bitte*. This I would use if e.g. I am showing something over the projector in the office and someone would come in through the door and leave it open so the light comes in. In any other case, I would say *Mach die Tür zu* or *Schließ die Tür* (very formal) and always followed by *bitte* ;)

Comment: @Bort: 'With the prefix "zu" coming from the adverb "zu" meaning "in direction of".' - that part of your comment is incorrect. It is "zu" in the meaning of "close"/"closed" (i.e. literally, *zumachen* means *to make closed*), in contrast to "auf", meaning "open"/"opened", as it also appears in *aufmachen*.

Comment: I don’t see what’s so hard to understand here—English _to_ has the same meaning, just not as commonly. “He pulled the door _to_” means that he closed (or almost closed) the door in English as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. The translated phrase would be something like "Schließ die Tür!" or "Mach die Tür zu!". "Tür zu!" is colloquial, and extremely impolite.
2. *Zu* does indeed have quite a few meanings, like *towards*, *at*, *too*, or *closed*.

Some examples of its usage:

> "Die Tür ist zu." - "The door is closed."
>
> "Ich bin zu Hause." -"I'm at home."
>
> "Das ist zu viel!" - "That's too much!"
>
> "Lasst uns zu ihr gehen." - "Let's go to her."

Comment: Thanks this really helped! I couldn't find anywhere on the internet that explained zu could mean "closed", I get the other meanings of zu ("directional").

Comment: "Schließ die Tür!" and "Mach die Tür zu!" are also rude. It is the missing "bitte" (please) that cause the rudeness, not the shortness of the order!

Comment: @Iris Depends largely on context. While definetly less polite, these two phrases are not inherently rude, in contrast to "Tür zu!".

Comment: I disagree that "Tür zu" is impolite. It depends a lot on the tone. Just as-is, it's fine. By the same account you could claim that leaving the door open is rude to the people in the room cause they catch a draft.

Answer (score 9):

The sentence is an ellipsis. As a complete sentence, it would be:

> Mach die Tür zu!

The verb is *zumachen* ("close"). *Tür zu!* is used as a very short order, and is usually impolite and used to express anger.

Comment: The magic of "bitte" (please): "Bitte Tür zu!" or "Tür zu, bitte!" is frequently used in my office.

Answer (score 1):

The word »zu« has at least nine different meanings:

1. Preposition, to describe a movement towards a target:

   > Michael ging **zu** seinem Bruder.
   >   Michael went **to** his brother.

   In combination with an article:

   > Tom lief **zum** Auto. (... **zu dem** ...)
   >   Tom ran **to the** car.
   >   Tom lief **zur** Schule. (... **zu der** ...)
   >   Tom ran **to the** school.
2. Preposition, to describe a relation:

   > Milch besteht **zu** einem großen Teil aus Wasser.
   >   Milk consists **to** a large extent of water.

   (You can also have articles joined with »to« as shown above)
3. Preposition, to describe that something happened at a certain time:

   > Ich werde dich **zu** Ostern besuchen.
   >   I'll visit you **at** Easter.

   (Joined articles are possible here too)
4. Adverb (most frequent usage in the phrase »ab und zu« which means »now and then« or »occasionally«)

   > Markus isst ab und **zu** Pizza.
   >   Markus occasionally eats pizza.
5. Grade Particle (I'm not sure if this term is correct. In German it is a »Gradparticle«):

   > Dieser Mantel ist mir **zu** groß.
   >   This suit is **too** big for me.
6. Konjunktion, together with *um*, *ohne* or *anstatt* as part of an infinite group.

   > Adrian fuhr ins Dorf, **um** Milch **zu** kaufen.
   >   Adrian drove to the village **to** buy milk.
   >
   > Dr. Weber arbeitete 60 Stunden durch, **ohne zu** schlafen.
   >   Dr. Weber kept working for 60 hours **without** sleeping.
   >
   > Die Kinder spielten, **anstatt zu** schlafen.
   >   The children were playing **instead of** sleeping.
7. Adverb, to describe, that an action ends in a drunk or stoned state:

   > Kevin hat sich **zu** gekifft.
   >   Kevin smoked pot until he was stoned.
8. Adverb, to describe, that an action ends in a closed state:

   > Walter macht die Tür **zu**.
   >   Walter **closes** the door.
9. Adjektive, to describe, that something is closed.

   > Die Tür ist **zu**.
   >   The door is **closed**.
   >
   > Überall sieht man nur noch **zue** Türen. (Bad style, but colloquial speech in some regions)
   >   You only see **closed** doors everywhere.

---

Your example is a variation of meaning 8 (Adverb to describe an action that ends in a closed state). »Tür zu« is a common ellipsis of this command:

> Mach die Tür zu!

Comment: So eine lange Antwort, wo doch die Frage offenbar off-topic ist.